# How to get distinct value in dropdown

Tags: jquery, json

I implemented a drop down where the list is coming from a JSON file but the JSON has duplicate values. How can I get the unique values in that dropdown? Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("data.json",function(obj) {
        $.each(obj, function(key, value){
            $("#dropdown1").append("<option value=" + key + ">" + value.name  + "</option>");
        });
    });
});
```

my JSON file looks like this:

```
[{
    "name": "abc1",
    "date": 1459461600000
}, {
    "name": "abc1",
    "date": 1459461600000
}, {
    "name": "abc1",
    "date": 1459461600000
}, {
    "name": "syn2",
    "date": 1459461600000
}, {
    "name": "syn2",
    "date": 1458834026000
}];
```

In the first dropdown now I'm getting 5 values, `abc1` 3 times and `syn2` 2 times.  I want to get both `abc1` and `syn2` only once. Please help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could achieve this by storing the names you've already added to the select in an array, and check that array before adding the next name. Something like this:

```
var usedNames = [];
$.each(obj, function(key, value) {
    if (usedNames.indexOf(value.name) == -1) {
        $("#dropdown1").append("<option value=" + key + ">" + value.name + "</option>");
        usedNames.push(value.name);
    }
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/fgcvyos5/)

You could de-dupe the array of objects, but this seems overkill when your only requirement is to get a single property in one loop.

Comment: Thank alot for ur help :)

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Comment: Best. Saved the day for me.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I would like to know what if date for following names abc1 and sync2 are different say abc1 = "date": 1459461600000 abc1 = "date": 1459461600001

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the obj values for duplicate then append to the select option like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $.getJSON("data.json",function(obj) {
   var duplicate= [];
   $.each(obj, function(key, value) {
     if (duplicate.indexOf(value.name) == -1) {
      $("#dropdown1").append("<option value=" + key + ">" + value.name + "</option>");
      duplicate.push(value.name);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Why post the exact same answer as me 10 minutes later?

Comment: it's happened because my internet connection is slow.